# Mentioning of ref in C# function parameters

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I made a function and I was to pass array of strings in it like  string[] aa= null
In function definition I made some update in it and then I found that its value was not updated when function was executed/returned .I am unable to understand which things in C# we are required to mention ref  keyword . Doesn't it always pass parameters by reference why need to mention ref ? which are the objects which require to be mentioned with   ref  in order to pass by reference ?

Code was like this ,just trying to show what was I doing,I was unable to update value without use of ref .

```
string[] temp = null 
foo(ref temp); 
//function definition
void foo (ref string[] temp) 
{
temp = {"Hello World ","You must be updated now"}
}
foreach(string s in temp)
System.Console.WriteLine(s)
```

Comment: hats off to So community , I read all the answers and learn a lot

Comment: So, why didn't your code work?

Comment: my code works , I needed to understand the concept , I am C++ developer , I learn new language by learning its very basic concepts

Comment: Heh, I misread your question. That notwithstanding, I'm glad I could clear some things up for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're pseudo code *should* work.  But, before we get to that, there are three things at play here: value types, reference types, and the "ref" keyword.

Value types are typically your simple basic types like int, double, etc.  string is a weird one as it is considered a value type.

More complex types, such as arrays and classes are reference types.

When you pass value types like ints and doubles then you are passing a copy of the value so if you pass int x = 10 into a method a change to x in the method won't be reflected once you leave the method. On the other hand, if you pass MyClass class1, any changes to the properties *within* class1 will be reflected outside the function. Just don't try to new up a new class1 inside your method because that won't change outside the caller.

If you want to change a value type within a method, you pass by ref. If you want to new up a new class or array, then you pass by ref.

One more thing: it's not that black-and-white between using out vs. ref.  You would use out only if the design for the method was to always create your class or array only inside the method. You would use ref on a reference type if you wanted to allow the possibility to create a new object.  Like,

```
    //function definition 
    void foo (ref string[] temp)  
    {
        if(temp == null)
        {
            temp = new string[] { "Hello World ", "You must be updated now" };
        }
        else
        { 
             // do something with the existing temp
        }
    }
```

Finally, if this is your actual code:

```
        string[] temp = null;
        foo(ref temp);

        foreach (string s in temp)
            System.Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Later:

```
    //function definition 
    void foo (ref string[] temp)  
    {
        temp = new string[] { "Hello World ", "You must be updated now" };
    }
```

Then, it should actually work.

Comment: Value types are typically your simple basic types like int, double, etc. string is a weird one as it is considered a value type.

More complex types, such as arrays and classes are reference types.

Answer (score 4):

You are a little mistaken in the intricacies. If you pass a reference object, then it is passes the reference by value (keep reading and hopefully it should begin to make more sense). However, that does not mean it is pass by ref. In fact, C# parameters are passed by value by default.

[Here is a good article that explains this pretty well](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)

And, this is the snippet that explains what I mean when I say you are passing the reference by value

> In C#, parameters are (by default) passed by value, meaning that
>   they are implicitly copied when passed to the method.  For value-type
>   parameters, this means physically copying the instance (in the same
>   way p2 was copied), while for reference-types it means **copying a
>   reference** (in the same way f2 was copied)

. However, in your case, you are passing in your object and then creating a new object with a new reference within your method. So, the original reference remains intact, you can see this by performing an update instead of a totally new creation. When you explicitly say ref, then you are now passing a reference to the reference, so it works because you are only working with the pointer to the reference, and when you create the new object it will be placed into that reference location.

As eouw0o83hf mentioned, if you are creating a totally new object, then you should use an `out` to signify this. `ref` is usually more for value objects, which are not passed by reference.

To summarize:

- If it is a value type, and you wish to update the value and have it reflect everywhere, then you need to use `ref`
- If it is a reference type

  - If you wish to update the value so that it reflects everywhere, then you can pass it in normally (no `ref` or `out`)
  - If you wish to create a totally new instance inside a method and have that reflected, then you should use `out`

**UPDATE**

[Here is an MSDN article explaining exactly what you are asking :)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szasx730.aspx)

Comment: yes please do check , to update it in a function or pass by reference it must required ref keyword , I also wish the scenarios where there is no way to use ref prefix for pass by reference

Comment: I have updated my description after verifying. If you have a background in C++ or another language where you deal with pointers, this will become obvious, otherwise hopefully I explained it well enough :)

Comment: @JustinPihony, you're first paragraph is a little contradicitory because the first half says it doesn't work ("the original reference stays intact" which it doesn't), but the second says it does work. Wait...let me try my shot at an answer....

Comment: @BradRem Thanks, I have re-aligned this so that it hopefully reads better and more clear.

Comment: Yeah, better, thanks. I was hoping we could make this clearer because most answers here are assuming his code fragment is incorrect. It actually should work (see my answer). I think he also doesn't understand what are value types and what are reference types.

Answer (score 2):

C# always passes parameters *by value*, unless you use the `ref` or `out` modifiers.

```
string[] temp = { "zero", "one", "two" };
MutateByVal(temp);
MutateByRef(ref temp);    

void MutateByVal(string[] arr)
{
    // arr and temp are separate references to the same array
    // the value of arr (a reference) is a copy of the value of temp

    // mutate the array referenced by arr
    arr[1] = "mutated!";
    // arr and temp still point at the same array
    // so both arr and temp now contain { "zero", "mutated!", "two" }

    // re-assign arr
    arr = new[] { "blah", "blah", "blah" };
    // arr and temp now point at different arrays
    // arr now contains { "blah", "blah", "blah" }
    // temp still contains { "zero", "mutated!", "two" }
}

void MutateByRef(ref string[] arr)
{
    // arr is an alias for temp
    // that is, they are two different names for the same reference

    // mutate the array referenced by arr
    arr[1] = "mutated!";
    // arr and temp are the same reference
    // so both arr and temp now contain { "zero", "mutated!", "two" }

    // re-assign arr
    arr = new[] { "blah", "blah", "blah" };
    // arr and temp are the same reference
    // so both arr and temp now contain { "blah", "blah", "blah" }
}
```

Comment: "C# always passes parameters by value" - I think that statement is a little garbled, since reference-typed objects are passed by reference. `MutateByRef` would work without the `ref` modifier too.

Comment: @eouw0o83hf: I disagree. What's garbled about *"C# always passes parameters by value, unless you use the ref or out modifiers"*? Reference-typed parameters are passed by value, it's just that the value happens to be a reference in those situations (see `MutateByVal` above).

Comment: @eouw0o83hf: And `MutateByRef` *does not* work without the `ref` modifier: As it stands, at the end of the method both `arr` and `temp` will contain `{"blah","blah","blah"}`, because *they are the same reference*; if you remove the `ref` modifier then at the end of the method `arr` will contain `{"blah","blah","blah"}` while `temp` will contain `{"zero","mutated!","two"}`, because *they are two separate references*.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're actually returning a whole new object rather than modifying an entry on an existing one. If you are assigning a new object, you should use `out` instead.

Here's an example showing how `out`, `ref`, and regular passing will work on an array arg. As you can see, the array is passed by reference whether or not `ref` is specified; however, if you return a whole new object, you need to specify `out`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] val;
        foo(out val);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", val));
        // Output: 1, 2

        bar(ref val);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", val));
        // Output: modified, 2

        bar2(val);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", val));
        // Output: modified again, 2

        Console.Read();
    }

    static void foo(out string[] temp)
    {
        temp = new string[]{"1", "2"};
    }

    static void bar(ref string[] temp)
    {
        temp[0] = "modified";
    }

    static void bar2(string[] temp)
    {
        temp[0] = "modified again";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that the way C# use pass by reference ?    is it possible to do it without ref or out keyword in any way ?

Comment: Yes, this is how reference passing works. If you want to modify members of an existing array, you do not need to specify `ref`. If you return a whole new object, you need to specify `out`.

Comment: But, you can still create a whole new object with 'ref'.  You use 'out' only if you want to create within and only within the callee method and the caller is always passing in an uninitialized variable.  Use 'ref' on a reference type if you may sometimes need to create a new object in the callee method.

Comment: The array *is not* "passed by reference whether or not `ref` is specified". For example, your `bar2` method's `temp` argument is passed *by value*. (Admittedly that value happens to be a reference in this case, but that's unrelated to whether it was passed by-val or by-ref).

Answer (score 1):

Without the `ref` the *reference to the array* is simply copied and passed to the method (by value - since a reference type's **value** is the reference to the object); allowing the method to access the same array, but it does ***not*** allow it to modify the caller's own reference.

That's what the `ref` (or indeed `out`) keyword is for.

However - you do not need to use `ref` if you simply want the method to alter the *object that is referenced* (depending on whether the type can be altered after construction - i.e. if it is immutable or not).

So this method will overwrite the first element of the passed array:

```
public static void foo(string[] ss)
{
  if(ss!=null && ss.Length > 0)
    ss[0] = "Overwritten";
}

public static void main()
{
   var strings = new[] { String.Empty, "Original" };
   foo(strings);
   Console.WriteLine(strings[0]); //will print 'Overwritten'.
}
```

What `foo` cannot do in the above code, however, is `new` the `ss` parameter and expect that to alter the *value of the reference* `strings` passed as the argument from `main`.

To do, we need to pass a *reference* to the `strings` local, which is where `ref` comes in.  If we do that - then `strings` in the `main()` can be altered, if passed null, to point to a new array:

```
public static void foo(ref string[] ss)
{
  if(ss==null || ss.Length == 0)
    ss= new string[1];

  ss[0] = "Overwritten";
}

public static void main()
{
   string[] strings = null
   foo(ref strings);
   Console.WriteLine(strings[0]); //will still print 'Overwritten'.
}
```

Comment: I only just realised that I'd actually forgotten to put in the `ref` in my second code blocks!  I've been up for twelve hours today, though, working for 11 of those (and still another 5 hours before bed) so that's my excuse. :D

Comment: Racing guy excuse , just kidding :D

Answer (score 1):

Any type passed in C# as a parameter is passed **by value**. So if this is an array of strings C# makes a copy of a reference (this is a reference type) and pass it in. But because this is a reference type, both variables (from inner method scope and outer parameter) would point to the **same object** in a managed heap (or large object heap).

The problem with your code is that you create a new variable (with incorrect syntax). To fix this you just use an indexer of an array directly, i.e.:

```
void foo (string[] temp) // create a copy of a reference to the string array
{
    temp[0] = "Boom"; // temp still points to the same object
}
-------------
string[] temp = new [] {"one", "two", "three"}; //outer variable
foo(temp); // behind the scene we have two variables pointing to the same array
foreach (string s in temp)
    System.Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of a class reference as being an "object ID".  If one has a variable `MyCar` of class type `Car`, the variable doesn't actually hold a car.  Instead, it holds the "object ID" of a car which is actually stored elsewhere.  If `MyCar` holds "#1543", the statement `MyCar.Color = CarColors.Purple;` won't actually modify variable `MyCar`.  Instead, it will tell the system "Object #1543 should be a `Car`.  Set its `Color` property to `CarColors.Purple."  In many cases, a routine which passes a variable of type`Car`will simply want the called code to do something with the`Car`identified by that variable.  In a few cases, however, one may be necessary to let the called code change the object ID stored within`MyCar`itself, so that it points to an entirely different instance of`Car`.

In your particular case, the object in question is an array.  The called routine creates a whole new array, but the caller starts out with `temp` equal to null.  The only way the caller is going to see the new array is if a reference to it gets stored into `temp`.  Otherwise the caller will continue to see whatever array `temp` had before (or `null`, if no array reference was stored there).